# How can I use the covariant "Derived" in a base class's property where Type is needed?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I have a BaseRepository class.  I want to use the Derived class from BaseRepository (call it JobSeekerRepository) in ILogger.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T>
{
     private readonly ILogger<Derived> _repositoryLogger;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `ILogger<JobSeekerRepository>` work?

Comment: Maybe add it as a generic parameter? E.g. `abstract class BaseRepository<T, Derived>`

Comment: This coupling seems wrong

Comment: Why is that logger private and not protected?

Comment: @Maroun Because this is a base class and I will have many derived repositories.

Comment: @Sasha That was it - thank you!